# Powershell window taking long time to close after clicking red X

Tags: powershell

If I open a powershell console and do this command for example :

```
"test"
```

when I click the red X (top right) to close the window, it goes away instantly. If I have a running/"pending" command like `read-host` and click the red X, it hangs for at least 5 seconds before disappearing.

What is the deal with that? It's not doing it in another test machine (windows 7 pro) but on this domain machine, it does it.

Any idea if a module or something could cause this? Pretty annoying to wait all the time for windows to close. Thank you

[image]

Comment: *Red* X? Do you have a screenshot of that?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers He is talking about the window close button.

Comment: I would assume you just have an issue with the system maybe? Trying Running `SFC /SCANNOW`, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, disk cleanup, and then restart. If that doesn't work try updating or reinstalling powershell.

Comment: @NickW - I know but I've never seen it red. I'm wondering if he's using another shell of some kind.

Comment: It's the native powershell shell (%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) Windows Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601 (Windows 7 Pro)

Comment: SFC, DISM and cleanups didn't work, using -noprofile didn't improve either, i'm now trying the updated powershell (6.0.2) from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.2/PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x86.msi  and it fixed it!!

Comment: Let me rephrase that to "I've never noticed it being red when hovered over". OP answered his own question, case closed.

Comment: My initial guess would be that a module is causing this behavior. To eliminate if it is a module type `powershell -noprofile -command "sleep 300"` into the run line then try to close. If you still have the issue it isn't a module. And do you happen to be running AVG? Also, check out [this article](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2804) about the same issue

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Move you mouse  over the "X" button and it will highlight red xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to latest stable Powershell CORE  release (6.0.2) fixed it completly.

HOWEVER, I have a lot of scripts which don't run right with this CORE version. That's a shame since it fixed my problem.

What I did was upgrade WFM instead, to version 5.1 and the problem is gone. So try that if you have that very annoying issue.

Comment: Now that you are on the core version, uninstall it and reinstall the old version. The Core version probably did a good job at uninstalling your previous version and cleaned up w/e was causing the problem, so I theorize that your issue may be resolved by going back.

Comment: I upgraded by installing WFM 5.1 (now using ps version 5.1.14409.1005) Problem is gone! Either it was what you said, or just the WFM 5.1 fixed it somehow.